# Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: .net, ssh, ssh.net

I am using the below code using **Renci.SshNet**, I generated credentials from Putty and it works perfectly fine with the ssh form Terminal as well as using the code below.

However, Now I have another private/public key to use in production, it works using from the terminal, even in python code as well, but below code raises an exception as

```
try
{
    var privateKeyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyFilePath);
    var privateKeyAuth = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, privateKeyFile);

    var sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);

    sshClient.Connect();

    // Perform SSH operations...
    // For example, execute a command on the server:
    SshCommand sshCommand = sshClient.RunCommand("ls -l");
    string commandResult = sshCommand.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(commandResult);

    sshClient.Disconnect();
    sshClient.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

I want to be able to connect to ssh client using my private key with which I can ssh in terminal, (It's required on local host, evn consol application raises same error as
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Key is set as 
AuthenticationMethod[] auths = new AuthenticationMethod[1];
auths[0] = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyFilePath));

var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("ip of server", 22, username, auths
);

Comment: Do not post information in comments. Edit everything into your question + You didn't tell us what exception do you get and where. + I do not understand what you mean by *"It's required on local host, evn consol application raises same error as Permission denied (publickey)"* + Log of the successful connection in terminal might be useful too.

Comment: @martin, I understand, but the stackoverflow editor was trying to be oversmart, by asking indent on code those I already provided. 
while already facing a trouble, I wasnt able to properly format a question, so had to put the rest of information in the comments.

Comment: The exception I am getting is Error: Permission denied (publickey).

Unhandled exception. Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: Permission denied (publickey).
   at Renci.SshNet.ClientAuthentication.Authenticate(IConnectionInfoInternal connectionInfo, ISession session)
   at Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo.Authenticate(ISession session, IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.CreateAndConnectSession()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()

Answer (score 0):

It seems SSH.NET doesn't support rsa-sha which is used by some old sftp servers. We fix the issue by replacing SSH.NET with a commercial library Chilkat.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to OpenSSH key, it helped me with v2024.0.0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).